# Check geometry point distance with next point

Tags: postgresql, postgis

This is my olocation table:

```
create table olocations
(
  id                 uuid not null
    constraint oid
    primary key,
  lat                double precision,
  lng                double precision,
  "deviceId"         text,
  topic              text,
  "userId"           uuid,
  "userName"         text,
  "creationDateTime" timestamp with time zone,
  shape              geometry,
  "appName"          text,
  "appVersion"       text
);
```

I want to check geometry point distance with next point until it's distance between them was less than 15 meters:

```
SELECT olocations.id,
    olocations."userId",
    olocations."deviceId",
    olocations."creationDateTime",
    olocations.shape,
    row_number() OVER ()
FROM olocations
    where st_distance(shape, (select shape from olocations
                                             where // ????  )) <= 15
GROUP BY olocations.id, olocations."creationDateTime"
ORDER BY olocations."creationDateTime"
```

In `st_distance()` method for first parameter i set first point but how can i set next point as second parameter?

After that i want to make multiline between those point the distance between them was less than 15 meters.How could i do that?

Comment: Thanks dude @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: What do you mean by "multiline between them". For example if we have 5 points in 15 meters from your what we should create 1. Outer border 2. Linestring between all 5 result point  joined to one multilinestring 3. Linestrings between your point and results points? Or maybe something diffrent?

Comment: Do I good understand that you want to find for all points in "olocations all other points in distance 15 meters from "olocations"?

Comment: look this image http://pasteall.org/pic/8cd78a577bdf4297fc5309b7713bff93  I want points that have less than 15 meter make a line and  there is a distance between the points more than 15 meters away @GrzegorzGrabek

Comment: One more request. COuld you show few records from olocations. As far as I understood olocations are points but on picture it looks like they are linestrings. Also is ID is unique or it is some kind of grouping records to know it is one route?

Comment: Creating linestrings from large data set is possible but will be terribly slow and inefficient. The result will be incorrect in terms of real paths from one location to its destination.
Could you describe your idea , maybe there is better solution then taking milions/thousends of points and try to create something from it?!

Comment: This is a part of my olocations table http://pasteall.org/pic/3f9a3dd09b295880314cad422777391d and this is my script for creating view to create line string https://pastebin.com/Ca7QWNPG and it's result http://pasteall.org/pic/bf9af93db8c1132586a71c6c0df83223 .In it's result 15 meter distance Is not considered @GrzegorzGrabek

Comment: I have used `date_trunk` for grouping by a day for example `2018-08-21 00:00:00.000000` as you can see on result picture.Now i want Influence 15 meter on my query. I want my view script result it's like this http://pasteall.org/pic/8cd78a577bdf4297fc5309b7713bff93 according by a day for each user  @GrzegorzGrabek

Comment: I have created this query https://pastebin.com/9f6fTXG4 and i do not know it's result is true or it is wrong @GrzegorzGrabek

Answer (score 0):

I've changed query according to new information. 
First, we ranking our records by "creationDateTime" in partition made by userId and deviceId. We also group records by user, device and day from creatioDateTime. -- CTE ol_dt

Then we create lines between points joining them inside groups and by our ranking (so we join our point with next point in time from same user and device in particular day) -- CTE lines

Last thing we join all lines from point to point to one (multi)linestring still in groups.

```
with ol_dt as (SELECT row_number() over (partition by "userId", "deviceId" 
                                          order by "creationDateTime") rnk,
                       rank() over (order by "userId", "deviceId", 
                                              date("creationDateTime")) rnk2,
                       o."userId",
                       o."deviceId",
                       date(o."creationDateTime") as day,
                       o.shape
                  FROM olocations o),
      lines as (select ol_dt."userId", ol_dt."deviceId", ol_dt.day, 
                       st_makeline(ol_dt.shape, ol_dt2.shape) as geom
                  from ol_dt, ol_dt ol_dt2
                 where ol_dt.rnk2=ol_dt.rnk2
                   and ol_dt.rnk+1=ol_dt2.rnk)
select "userId", "deviceId", day, st_union(geom) geom
   from lines
  group by "userId", "deviceId", day
```

For bigger datasets (houndreds of thousends or millions or more records) when you want to make it for the whole dataset at once.

```
Create temp table ol_dt as
SELECT row_number() over (partition by "userId", "deviceId" 
                          order by "creationDateTime") rnk,
       rank() over (order by "userId", "deviceId", date("creationDateTime")) rnk2,
        o."userId",
        o."deviceId",
        date(o."creationDateTime") as day,
        o.shape
  FROM olocations o;
create index on ol_dt using btree (rnk, rnk2);
create index on ol_dt using gist(shape);
```

Then create table with second CTE

```
create temp table lines as
select ol_dt."userId", ol_dt."deviceId", ol_dt.day, 
       st_makeline(ol_dt.shape, ol_dt2.shape) as geom
  from ol_dt, ol_dt ol_dt2
 where ol_dt.rnk2=ol_dt.rnk2
   and ol_dt.rnk+1=ol_dt2.rnk;
```

And finally

```
 select "userId", "deviceId", day, st_union(geom) geom
   from lines
  group by "userId", "deviceId", day
```

Comment: Thanks dude i have a question, Why `where statement` is like: `where st_dwithin(o.shape, o2.shape, 15) and o."creationDateTime"=o2."creationDateTime"` Should we not check the first point with the second one of certain user? you checked first point with first point  of olocations table !! We should not use `lead` for next points of certain user ? @GrzegorzGrabek

Comment: For example `st_dwithin(o.shape, next o2.shape, 15)` ? @GrzegorzGrabek

Comment: I changed code http://codepad.org/DYRrww7U and this is result: 
http://pasteall.org/pic/3124d8b0d0f7e73a8c95f136e897d29f and look on qgis http://pasteall.org/pic/13c628c5f7a9351fc9efaca922df8153. I have specified with black pen, This part is not acceptable. How can i remove this? @GrzegorzGrabek

Comment: As I understood you group your data by "creationDateTime" and only joins inside such groups are possible. If not just remove this join condition and replace with other (any you like or needed). I don't know logic behind your data i've just seen your SQL query and structure of table. If you want to join them by userId sure join them. And this query doesn't join only first with first it joins first with all from same creationDateTime in distance of 15 meters.

Comment: As I said before - creating lines from some scattered points it is not a good idea. But if you want to do it i show you some start point. Much better solution would be joining them inside userID by the sequence of time.

Comment: Dude why you check distance of the points with itself? `st_dwithin(o.shape, o2.shape, 15)` ? `o.shape` and `o2.shape` are the same because o1.shape is o2.shape... ? @GrzegorzGrabek

Comment: o.shape and o2.shape are not the same. As I wrote it is point A vs all points in the distance of 15 meters. There will be of course the same point also but it is doesn't matter. If it is a problem for you just add in where condition o.id<>o2.id.

Comment: Then it checks it's shape with all shapes for all user , for example it checks the shape of user A with other user's shape?Yes? If i want to check shape, just for special user (user A ) i have to write where condition.Is it true? Why you checked `o."creationDateTime"=o2."creationDateTime"`? In the event that all shapes have different creationDateTime except itself !!! @GrzegorzGrabek

Comment: I add a condition on creationDateTime because in your query you grouped by creationDateTime (i thought that is daytime of data inserting for all points from user trip or something).
If creationDateTime is just creation time for single point just remove it. And yes if you want connect points only for one user then add condition for it o.userid=o2.userid and 0.userid="something".
The problem is what you want to do when for example in the range of 15 meters from point A there is 10 other points of the same user. How do you want to connect with them?

Comment: Dear friend, I want to explain my idea. I have  million row of 100 user  that have stored olocations's data.This users have a userid and device id but some user may have 2 devices so his user id has other device id. for example userA with userid =1 my have 2 device id (11,12).I need multi line string of each user for a day. @GrzegorzGrabek

Comment: My idea is , first i select all geometry location of each user grop by `userid` and `device id` and  `date_trunc('day' :: text, o."creationDateTime")` so it's result is a row per user for a day like this http://pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=3124d8b0d0f7e73a8c95f136e897d29f . Now i need to remove all points that has more than 15 meter with it's previous point. because when i create a line, output is http://pasteall.org/pic/13c628c5f7a9351fc9efaca922df8153 . @GrzegorzGrabek

Comment: The problem is here and i could not find appropriate solution for it!!! imagine i split point that has a problem and now i want to create a line. Again all point make a line and some line will across from rode or houses or ... this will not be accepted. What is your idae? @GrzegorzGrabek

Comment: Most important question is what is exactly "creationDateTime" if it is datetime of creation each point not group of points  then i think we can have a chance to create nice linestring for each user and each device. 
If not then second approach would be connect point by user and device but only to closest and not connected already.
If you answer me what is exactly creationdatetime then i will write query for it.

Comment: "creationDateTime"  is datetime of creation each point . That is mean when user move, point and it's dsatetime are  stored into table.@GrzegorzGrabek

Comment: I've changed the query in the answer. I hope it will make a day for you ;) If this work accept answer , pls.

Comment: I think you missing  `,` in end of `row_number` and `rank` method. Anyway, i got this error: `ERROR: column "lines.userId" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function Position: 781` @GrzegorzGrabek

Comment: Yes you are right. I've edited query, should be ok now

Comment: Thanks dude,i'll execute your query and announce you.I have a question, i run just first select of top ,why some `rnk` field is the same? for example i see couple of 1 or 3 !!! should not to unique ?@GrzegorzGrabek

Comment: The second rank is just to create groups for easier joins in later queries. Without it you have to join table ol_dt with itself by userId, diviceId and day(creationDateTime). With rnk2 caluclate in ol_dt CTE, you can join records just by ol_dt.rnk2=ol_dt2.rnk. If you don't like it just remove and join by 3 conditions described in my comment.

Comment: I run this query but after almost one hour i did not get any result.Now still working . it is `wetting for the query execution to complete ...` in table i have 1 million record  @GrzegorzGrabek

Comment: Add condition to first CTE (ol_dt) on userID and deviceID to filter small sample on start (choose small one). And check if results are ok with you. If yes then create tablle with first query and index btree index on columns rnk i rnk2 and gist index on shape. Then creata table with second CTE (lines). And finally use the last query.

Comment: First CTE(ol_dt) works fine after i select that but when i run second CTE(lines) and then i do select from line, this result is nothing and the same way on last query i got nothing.  @GrzegorzGrabek

Comment: I found typo in second CTE "ol_dt.rnk+1=ol_dt.rnk" should be "ol_dt.rnk+1=ol_dt2.rnk"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179962/discussion-between-grzegorz-grabek-and-sayres-kabir).